# Turning off parameter runAllTests to false while deploying code

Tags: metadata-api, metadata

In the migration tool, there is a parameter called- runAllTests. The same parameter can also be used for deploying code via metadata API. Can the parameter be set to false while deploying the code in production? If the value of the parameter is false, does it still run the test cases? I'm asking this because I was told that the test cases still run in production even if the parameter is turned off.

Answer (score 2):

> I was told that the test cases still run in production even if the parameter is turned off.

This is correct.

> As per the documentation it doesn't run when set to false. I have
>   tried the same in production env and can confirm that no test ran.

The above statement in the other answer is incorrect relatively Production.
Here is what documentation states about `runTests` & `runAllTests`
http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_deploying_ant_deploy.htm

> This parameter is ignored when deploying to a Salesforce production
>   organization. Every unit test in your organization namespace is
>   executed.

Comment: I am not clear on what you are saying. Were you able to shut off the tests by using this parameter? the questions is for production orgs.